# Titanium : Use Ti.UI.SIZE + myvar?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

What I'm trying to do is increase the height of each row of my ListView.
I set an height = **Ti.UI.SIZE** , unfortunately with this method , the height set to the row is too small.
I wish there was much space between the words and the start / end of row (a sort of padding that is used with css)

it's possible ? thanks

[image]

```
var template = {
    properties : {
        height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
        selectionStyle : Ti.UI.iPhone.ListViewCellSelectionStyle.NONE
    },
    childTemplates : [{
        type : 'Ti.UI.View',
        bindId : 'view',
        properties : {
            left : 0,
            width : 300,
            height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
            backgroundImage : "/images/blur_nero.png",
        },
        childTemplates : [{
            type : 'Ti.UI.Label',
            bindId : 'label',
            properties : {
                left : 5,
                width : 290,
                height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
                textAlign : "left",
                color : "white",
                font : {
                    fontSize : 10
                }
            }

        }]
    }]
};

var tabella = Ti.UI.createListView({
        width : 300,
        height : 375,
        bottom : 10,
        //separatorColor : 'transparent',
        separatorStyle : 'none',
        backgroundColor : 'transparent',
        separatorInsets : {
            left : 0,
            right : 0
        },
        showVerticalScrollIndicator : false,
        templates : {
            'plain' : template
        },
        defaultItemTemplate : 'plain',
        visible : false
    });

for (var i = 0; i < stagione[3].length; i++) {

            //var app_color = background_color[i];

            var dati_rec = stagione[3][i].split("#");

            var app_2 = dati_rec[1];
            if(app_2[0] == " "){
                app_2 = app_2.substring(1,app_2.length);
            }

            data_record.push({
                label : {
                    text : dati_rec[0] + "\n" + app_2
                },
                view : {
                    backgroundColor : "transparent"
                },
                properties : {
                    selectionStyle : Ti.UI.iPhone.ListViewCellSelectionStyle.NONE,
                    backgroundColor : "transparent"
                }
            });

}

intestazione.appendItems(data_record, {
            //animationStyle : Ti.UI.iPhone.RowAnimationStyle.TOP
});
```

Comment: you can give top , bottom and left properties to your label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to more space in top and bottom then you should use layout property to vertical for parent and then set top property of children as per your requirement.